# Structuring online documentation for a REST API

Tags: indexing, rest

I'm building my first Rest API which serialize data to JSON and XML formats. 
I would like to provide an index page to API clients, where they would be able to choose implemented endpoints.

What information do I need to include to make my API most useful, and how should I organize it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a very complex question for a simple answer.

You may want to take a look at existing API frameworks, like [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) Specification ([OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification)), and services like [apiary.io](http://apiary.io/) and [apiblueprint.org](https://apiblueprint.org/).

Also, here's an example of the same REST API described, organized and even styled in three different ways. It may be a good start for you to learn from existing common ways.

- https://api.coinsecure.in/v1
- https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/originalUI
- https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/slateUI#!/Blockchain_Tools/v1_bitcoin_search_txid

At the very top level I think quality REST API docs require at least the following:

- a list of all your API endpoints (base/relative URLs)
- corresponding HTTP GET/POST/... method type for each endpoint
- request/response MIME-type (how to encode params and parse replies)
- a sample request/response, including HTTP headers
- type and format specified for all params, including those in the URL, body and headers
- a brief text description and important notes
- a short code snippet showing the use of the endpoint in popular web programming languages

Also there are a lot of JSON/XML-based doc frameworks which can parse your API definition or schema and generate a convenient set of docs for you. But the choice for a doc generation system depends on your project, language, development environment and many other things.